# margin:auto not working with width:auto

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to first div be center.

margin:auto not working with width:auto.

width value must be auto

```
  <div style="display:block;margin:auto;width:auto">
      <div style="background-image:url(assets/img/asd.png) "></div>
      <div style="background-image:url(assets/img/abc.png)"></div>
      <div style="background-image:url(assets/img/asd.png)"></div>
      <div style="background-image:url(assets/img/asd.png)"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking and what you are trying to achieve. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't. Obviously you are trying to center these images. Just use this instead:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <div style="display: inline-block;background-image:url(assets/img/asd.png) "></div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;background-image:url(assets/img/abc.png)"></div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;background-image:url(assets/img/asd.png)"></div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;background-image:url(assets/img/asd.png)"></div>
</div>
```

And it would be better to use classes and a stylesheet instead of inline CSS....

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Your outer div is 100% wide and it fills the entire window, which makes it pointless to be centered.

Rather, you should maybe wrap a container around your code which has a width in either px or % and set `margin: 0 auto;` on that. And your code inside would then be set to `width: 100%;`

If, on the other hand you would want your content inside to be centered, use `text-align: center;`